# How is standard deviation different from average deviation?

Tags: statistics

Standard deviation is used as a measure of deviation or distribution in a sample or a population.Similarly mean is used as a measure of something in a group(say average marks of a group of students).How is standard deviation different from average deviation?

Comment: But the standard deviation is not the "average deviation of the elements from the mean".

Comment: But it is used as a measure of deviation or distribution in a sample or a population.Similarly mean is used as a measure of something in a group(say average marks of a group of students).How is standard deviation different from mean?

Comment: you should point out specific assumptions/contextual things  to make it explicit. Statistics and mathematics have a large variety of problems and alternative solutions. It is not desireable to make sublimal assumptions to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_i)$ be a data set. Denote by the average deviation $D$. Then

$$ D = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu) $$

and

$$ \sigma = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \mu) ^2 } $$

Certainly two different quantities. Variance (the square of standard deviation) measure the average **squared** deviation - i.e., the average positive distance to the mean.

Comment: But if average deviation can be used as a measure of distribution in a group, why was another quantity(standard deviation) defined? Or why was variance defined?(why should we measure the average of squared deviation when deviation is all we are concerned about.)

Comment: We want positive numbers to measure distances. Variance measures spread and better represents how tightly packed the data is. Average deviation doesn't really do a good job of that. TL;DR: Don't worry about it. It'll only complicate things.

Comment: Please suggest me some good books(introductory level ) to understand these things in statistics.